# When and why did the custom to have young children end Musaph Shabbat davening begin?

Tags: shabbat, chazzan-prayer-leader, minor-katan-child, musaf

In most shuls that I have attended (mainly Nusach Ashkenaz), young children (below Bar Mitzvah age, usually) finish the Shabbat davening at the end of Musaph. I.e., they sing from *En K'elokeinu* through *Adon Olam*.

How and why did this custom begin?

I have a concern with their doing this. While this is not a scientific poll, I asked about 20 young kids (ages 6 - about 11) if they actually recite the entire *Pitum Haktoret*, the passage after *En K'elokeinu*. All said, no. The words were too hard from them to pronounce, and I guess, being that there is no song to them, I can understand, somewhat, why this is harder than "Aleinu". OK, if, technically, you're a *Shaliach Tzibbur*, aren't you supposed to say everything? Is it correct to assign a kid who can't do it and just says the ending "for show"?

I can probably say the same thing about *An'im Zemirot*, though, it seems that since they have to sing it aloud, that may be an incentive for them to pronounce the words better. (When I was a younger boy (not a "Yunger man"), my chazzan would not let me sing Anim Zemirot, exactly because of this concern that the words were too hard to pronounce.)

In short, a combo question - why did he custom become this way, and is it the correct thing to use kids that can't pronounce the words or don't even bother in the first place?

Comment: It's not like _Pitum Haketoret_ is part of _davening_. It's just a bit of learning at the end. So to call the kid a _shaliach tzibbur_ is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @Daniel Not completely following your claim. It's in the Siddur as apart of Musaf. How is not part of davening? As a matter of fact, it seems somewhat important, as it becomes a "prereq" for Kaddish Derabbanan that follows.

Comment: In my minyan, Anim Z'mirot is recited after Shacharit. Pitum Hak'toret is said after Musaf. That a child doesn't say all the words is not important, albeit they should get a go-ahead as to when to continue and should try reading something in it during this alloted time.

Comment: And as a comment, the children pronouce all of Anim Z'mirot fine. It's the adults who can't pronounce the 2nd word in the first response line.

Comment: At our shul, the "children" at or around bar mitzvah age asked the gabbai **on their own** not to be assigned the last part of the davening. As a result, the shliach tzibbur finishes everything. The only part that a child does is adon olam, and the ones who do it are very careful to do it correctly (such as my grandson (:-) )

Comment: @DanF Davening ends with Kaddish Shalem. Everything else is add ons that some people say. Kaddish Derabanan isn't related to Davening; it's related to public Torah study, as you know. Plenty of things in the Siddur aren't Davening, as you know.

Comment: @DoubleAA AFAIK, Aleinu and Song of the day are.

Comment: @DanF Borderline for some definition of "davening", but Ok. I'd say they're the oldest and most widely accepted post-davening additions.

Comment: @sabbahillel Sounds like a great example that the kids themselves have taken this initiative. Usually, parents "push" their kids to do it. I guess it's something to keep them occupied so they don't run around and make noise?

Comment: In these shuls the katan says kaddish? Wouldn't it be more important that the person who says kiddush says all of the words?

Comment: @Dude Since in most shuls Kaddish Yasom and Kaddish D'rabbanan are said by those who need to in the congregation, it does not matter who says from Ein Keilohainu on (as far as that aspect goes).

Comment: That was kinda my point I was getting at. If the concern is it will be too difficult for a child to say the person being an adult in the kehilla as well as others will have already said everything that kaddish is afterwards and having the katan as shliach tzibur at this point is really only a matter of chinuch

Comment: @Dude Perhaps, within this discussion, I need a definition of both what "Shaliach tzibbur" actually means in terms of what he should say and when "davening" actually ends. From the above comments, I get a sense that once Kaddish Shalem after Musaf has been said, a Shat'z is not required. I'm inferring, then, that all the other items either need not be said, or it doesn't require a Shat'z. Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: @DanF Depends on what you mean by "need." There are lots of things that we "need" to do that aren't _davening_.

Comment: What you call "davening" and what you don't call "davening" is a question of semantics (cc DoubleAA). The point is not whether it's called "davening" (nor whether the leader is called a "_shatz_", cc @Daniel ) but whether we have to be concerned that the leader says every word. I fail to see why that should be a concern for the _k'tores_. (It's not like he's being _motzi_ anyone with it, anyway.) Can you [edit] in why you think that's a concern?

Answer (score 1):

I remember hearing once that the Vilna Gaon (I think) said that Anim Zemirot is one of the holiest pieces of tefillah and it should only be said on Yom Kippur.  I wonder whether since children are considered to be pure and their aveirot are not counted before Bar Mitzvah, if we are going to sing it every Shabbat, we have children do it as adults are not pure enough to do it.  I don't have a source for that idea - just something that occurred to me once.  Once children are singing Anim Zemirot, it makes sense that it could easily have become extended to the other final parts of davening.

Possibly there is also an idea of Chinuch since we want the children to learn how to lead the davening so that we have the next generation of baalei tefillah and this is a good starting point?

Comment: IMO, Anim Zemirot is not a good chinuch starting point. No yeshiva that I know of begins their Siddur chinuch with Anim Zemirot. It'ssimpy more practical to start kids with the more common daily davening parts such as Shema, Birkot Hashachar and Amidah. Often, davening is done in school at the start of the day. Anim Zemirot, then, would most likely not be a factor.

Comment: I'm talking about Chinuch for being baal tefillah, not for personal davening.